# How to access Tkinter window in another module?

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I am making an app in which there will be a button on the window which when clicked will call a function in another module in the same program. Please help me do that.

**main.py**

```
 from tkinter import *
 
 import module1

 win = Tk()
 
 button=Button(win,text="Button")
 
 button.place(x=1,y=5)
 
 button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",function1)
 
 win.geometry("1100x650")
 
 mainloop()
```

**module1.py**

```
 def function():
     
     label=Label(win,text="Hii")
     
     label.place(x=5,y=9)
```

When I run this code nothing happens. Please tell me what could be my mistake?

Comment: What does this have to do with `tkinter`? You should relook into the basics of python.

Comment: There are few issues: 1) `bind` on empty string; 2) `function1` is not defined; 3) did not import tkinter in `module1.py`; 4) `win` is not defined in `module1.function()`.

Comment: If you got my objective the help me achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to reference `function()` in `module1.py`, use `module1.function` since you use `import module1` to import `module1`.
- Since you used `bind()` but `function()` does not have argument, so you need to use `lambda` to execute it. Suggest to use `command` option of button instead of `bind()`.
- You need to import `tkinter` in `module1.py`.
- `win` cannot be accessed in `module1`, you need to pass it as an argument.

Below are modified `main.py` and `module1.py`:

**main.py**

```py
from tkinter import *
import module1

win = Tk()
win.geometry("400x250")

button = Button(win, text="Button", command=lambda: module1.function(win))
button.place(x=1, y=5)

win.mainloop()
```

**module1.py**

```py
from tkinter import *

def function(win):
    label = Label(win, text="Hii")
    label.place(x=50, y=90)
```